# How to transform a struct into a list of maps

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this struct (data comes from DB):

```
%MyProj.Event{imgPath: ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg"], videoPath: "video/1.mpg", youTubePath: nil}
```

I need to convert it to a list of maps/keyword lists (like this):

```
[
  %{imgPath: "images/1.jpg", videoPath: nil, youTubePath: nil},
  %{imgPath: "images/2.jpg", videoPath: nil, youTubePath: nil},
  %{imgPath: "images/3.jpg", videoPath: nil, youTubePath: nil},
  %{imgPath: nil, videoPath: "video/1.mpg", youTubePath: nil}
]
```

This is to be converted and passed inside a `render` function where I have access to the Struct as @links:

```
<%= render MyProj.ModulesView, "Component.html",
    data: @links
%>
```

Comment: What's the logic here? Can `videoPath` be a list of strings or nil? Can `youTubePath` be a string or list of strings? What about `imgPath`?

Comment: And can you show the `Component.html` if possible? Generating that kind of list doesn't seem like a good design to me at a first glance (seeing the template code would make it clearer).

Comment: @Dogbert I need to pass ´data´ in a format that is enumerable to be used inside a ´<%= for {i, id} <- Enum.with_index(@data) do %>´ in my ´Component.html.eex´ . Each of ´imgPath, videoPath and youTubePath´ are either a ´string´ or ´nil´.

Comment: @PauloJaneiro are either a string **a list of strings** or nil?

Comment: I guess you don't need the nils at all, because `map = %{a: 1}` & `IO.puts map.b => nil`

Comment: @webdeb. Yes, but I was (mistakingly) using (.) dot notation in my templates instead of `[:key]` to access the values and, as such, by not using `nil` I was getting an error because they were missing. Now, knowing the this difference I don't need to use them anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
defmodule MyProj.Event do
  defstruct [:imgPath, :videoPath, :youTubePath]

  def convert(%MyProj.Event{} = event) do
    keys = [:imgPath, :videoPath, :youTubePath]
    empty = for key <- keys, into: %{}, do: {key, nil}
    for key <- keys, path <- List.wrap(Map.get(event, key)) do
      %{empty | key => path}
    end
  end
end
```

```
iex(1)> struct = %MyProj.Event{imgPath: ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg"], videoPath: "video/1.mpg", youTubePath: nil}
%MyProj.Event{imgPath: ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg"],
 videoPath: "video/1.mpg", youTubePath: nil}
iex(2)> MyProj.Event.convert(struct)
[%{imgPath: "images/1.jpg", videoPath: nil, youTubePath: nil},
 %{imgPath: "images/2.jpg", videoPath: nil, youTubePath: nil},
 %{imgPath: "images/3.jpg", videoPath: nil, youTubePath: nil},
 %{imgPath: nil, videoPath: "video/1.mpg", youTubePath: nil}]
```

Comment: It really works! But I must confess that I can't understand/follow how `convert` works line 3 to 5...

Comment: By reading documentation I now understand your logic except this two: `for key <- keys, path <- Something do
 %{empty | key => path}`. Can you point relevant info please (about this last line and the two iterations inside a `for`.